# How to use WebView for React or Vue web project?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, webview

I am currently trying to find a way to use WebView on the web to point to another application that uses a different technology.

When looking for WebView for React or Vue, they always point to the Mobile framework version (ie: React Native, NativeScript) that has the WebView component built in.

In my case, I just want to use WebView with no intention of using a mobile framework.

I also looked into iFrame but it doesn't always work.

Is there any alternatives?
Can I use React Native as a web project and use WebView to point to another url?

Comment: And what is that exactly why do you need to use WebView? Maybe it's not a good use case for this technology? Is the other application that uses a different technology a native application? Maybe this would help a bit ;) 
https://dev.to/alexiey91/interaction-between-vue-js-webview-and-native-apps-15e2